# Flutter - How to put this string code into stateless widget or stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, split, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD3wJ.jpg)
Can someone show me how to add this Example 1 to stateless or stateful widget in Flutter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Please go through this first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've come across the classic inability to use a variable you've just defined.

Here's the best solution:

Go ahead and define the variable in the class

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<String> singleWord = "im so cool".split(" ");
  (...)

}
```

And then you can **use** that variable in any function. For example, the "initState" function is called once when the class is initiated, so we can put our usage of the function in that.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<String> singleWord = "im so cool".split(" ");
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    singleWord.forEach((e) => print(e));
    super.initState();
  }
 (...)

}
```

If you want to use the same function multiple times then just remove the `@override` and name the function something that makes sense. E.g. `singleWordSplitPrint`

However, please do NOT use the variable inside the build method as the build method is called **way** more than you think - especially when you're just starting out and your `setState((){})`'s aren't perfect!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you i got it now! By the way if you don't mind i have another problem which is i tried to display the output in flutter app and fail to do so, do you know how?

Comment: @JoeJoe Could you give me a little more information on what exactly you tried to do? :)